# Chrome and Bootstrap fixed navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, navbar

Been using bootstrap for awhile and its now just had a small hickup.
Getting the same issue on their example. So for cleaner code ill use theirs...

http://newsapps.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Win 8.1 pro
Using chrome 41.0.2272.101m (also just updated to this.. so noticed on previous version)
Disabled all extensions, also uninstalled and reinstalled, cleared cache.

Screen res: dual screen = 1920x1080 and 1680x1050

Problem: No nav bar content. Its rendered at over 7000px wide, and content is floated right or centered.
If I resize my window to say 700x400 the navbar gets a width of 2943px.
Also of note is that now the jumbotron on that page is now not display..
Its .container gets 1170px width? Reappears though when resizing.

Debugging chrome on my own site it appears that the viewport meta tag may be a cause. Removing that it performs fine, But also removing the position:fixed solves it. Though naturally leaves it with styling issues...

Using Dev tools and selecting a device works fine. No device, no menu....
Its like the viewport and media queries are not working correctly but ONLY on my PC?

I cant reproduce it on my home PC or work colleges. I cant find any info on it and for a responsive site the view-port is needed.

Driving me nuts.... quick fix, use FF but if clients get this issue or others have it?

Cant add screenshot as < 10 rep (sorry..)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested.
After clearing the cache, uninstalling, resetting all settings and nothing working I decided to play around again in the 'device mode' pane again, as I figured this is the most likely place it'll be due to the view port meta tag seeming to affect it.

I use this pane to test sizes and resolutions and then turn it off. BUT there must be some sort of setting in that that stuck. Un-ticking everything and changing devices doesnt work..(and resetting didnt either) but you will notice a circle icon with a cross in it in the top left. Like the 'ban' symbol and hovering over it will say 'reset all overrides'.  Click it..

No idea HOW an override gone in there, or why resetting the browser, uninstalling etc would not reset them.. or where you can find them, but there you go. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

@Logan I was having the same issue. Resetting the override doesn't work for me but switching Chrome to a new user does, bizarrely.